# conditional validation in jquery validation engine

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validation-engine

I have a checkbox and a textbox.
I require that if a checkbox is ticked then textbox becomes compulsary.
Vice versa if the textbox is filled the checkbox becomes compulsary.

So sample would be

Name of Item -   Checkbox -  Expiry Date
Name of Item2 -   Checkbox2 -  Expiry Date2

Data is fetched from the database in the array using a query.

My code looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sea").validationEngine();
   });

function industry(field, rules, i, options) {    
var atLeastOneIsChecked = $('input[name="extraqualification[]"]:checked').length > 0;
if (atLeastOneIsChecked == 1 )        {
if(document.getElementById('extraqualificationexpirydate<?php echo $extraqual['Id']?>').value=='')
{
   return "Please supply a certificate expiry";
}else{} }
    } </script>
```

Comment: 1) please state your question clearly 2) please post your markup

Comment: Hi NiftyDude - I am trying to validate using validation engine from http://www.position-absolute.com/category/javascript/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need conditional required validation. There is a `condRequired` method that you can use as follows:

```
<input value="" type="text" name="test" id="test" />
<input class="validate[condRequired[test]]" type="text" id="test_2" name="test_2"/>
```

Also, make sure you are using version 2.6 or above.